# Which way to determine empty string is better?

Tags: python

In my code, I need to test whether or not a string is empty for millions of times. The question is, which way is better/faster: `if str == ''` or `if len(str) == 0`. If there's better ways to do this, please share. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Don't optimize if you don't have to. Write you code in a pythonic matter then figure out bottlenecks. Niklas B's answer is the most pythonic, however it most likely does not matter what solution you use in the end in matter of efficiency and speed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please don't name your variables `str`, as this is the name of a built-in function.

So if you can be sure that `s` is a string (which hopefully is the case), you can just use

```
if not s:
  # s is the empty string
```

This should be the [preferred](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) [way](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#testing-for-truth-values) of doing such a check. It also works for `list`s, `set`s and `dict`s. Performance-wise, there's probably no noticeable difference, but you can of course measure that to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So why is this better? And does this work for lists too?

Comment: @lllluuukke under the hood it performs the check `if len(str) == 0` and is much cleaner.

Comment: This is what is recommended in the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  (Note that you shouldn't use `str` as a variable name.)

Comment: This may not be of concern to you, but if your code makes a distinction between None and empty strings, 'if s' will introduce subtle and very irritating  bugs in to your code.

Comment: @sr2222: That's why I wrote that one has to be sure that `s` is a string in that situation.

Comment: @NiklasB. quite so.  But I just wanted to be explicit about this, as if you are coming from other languages (say, Java), such a distinction may not be immediately clear to you.  Just because Python has no concept of null string does not mean people may not be accustomed to thinking about it.